# I'am getting "[violation] avoiding using document write()" error when adding a body tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

when creating a basic html layout as shown below, i keep getting "[violation] avoiding using document write()" error. However when i remove the body tag, the error is gone.
Does anyone know why its happening and is there any alternative for me to use.
Thanks,

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

#### Update:

The source tab on chrome developer console, is highlighting the line inside the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script id="bs_script">
    //<![CDATA[ document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname)); //]]>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest showing your code as well, not just your HTML

Comment: Hi Dane hope you are fine, thats the thing i havent written any code yet. I only have HTML so far. The source tab on chrome developer console, is highlighting the line inside the body tag.   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body><script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>

    
</body>
</html>

Comment: The `script` tag within the HTML could be the issue. Rather don't post code as a comment, edit your question and add it in.

Comment: Hi Dane, sorry for adding the code in the comment ill remember for next time :). You were right script tag was the issue. I used Browsersync for my  live browser reload and they insert a document.write() script tag into any first <body> tag, even if that first tag is commented out. So i am using a different live browser reload now and i dont get the error anymore. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer and included your note about Browsersync creating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The script tag within the HTML is the issue.

#### Additionally: Browsersync inserts a document.write() script tag into any first  tag, even if that first tag is commented out. So using a different live browser reload solved the issue